# Lucene.net - read past eof Exception

Tags: c#, exception, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.net and I am getting the Exception read past EOF while I'm trying to get the term frequency vectors, here is my code:

```
public class DocumentData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }    
}

public static string CONTENT = "Body";

// Method that adds a new document to the index
public static void AddToLuceneIndex(DocumentData documentData, IndexWriter writer)
{
    //remove older index entry
    var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id", documentData.Id.ToString()));
    writer.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);

    //add a new index entry
    var doc = new Document();

    //add lucene fields mapped to db fields
    doc.Add(new Field("Id", documentData.Id.ToString() ?? "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("Title", documentData.Title ?? "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field(CONTENT, documentData.Body ?? "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));

    //add entry to index
    writer.AddDocument(doc);
}    

// Gets the term frequency vectors for the ids in docs
private static ITermFreqVector[] GetVectors(int[] docs, FSDirectory directory)
{
    var reader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
    var answer = docs.Select(x => reader.GetTermFreqVector(x, LuceneSearch.CONTENT)).ToArray(); // the exception is thrown at this point
    reader.Dispose();
    return answer;
}
```

I add some documents to the index, then I get the frequency vectors for these documents and all is ok, but when I add documents again and I call to the GetVectors function then the exception is thrown. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does the `docs` parameter contain? Can you show the code that calls your failing method?

Comment: @JfBeaulac the error was that in docs I was passing the ids of documents in the database (it's wrong). I fix this and all is ok. Thanks for your reply.